# Benefit of async function

Tags: javascript

The following code is taken from the MDN site:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

```
function getProcessedData(url) {
  return downloadData(url) // returns a promise
    .catch(e => {
      return downloadFallbackData(url); // returns a promise
    })
    .then(v => {
      return processDataInWorker(v); // returns a promise
    });
}
```

The docs say that this can be converted to an async function like this:

```
async function getProcessedData(url) {
  let v;
  try {
    v = await downloadData(url); 
  } catch(e) {
    v = await downloadFallbackData(url);
  }
  return processDataInWorker(v);
}
```

I don't understand what the benefit of the async function is in this example because both approaches are asynchronous and both take 9 lines of code.

Comment: The benefit is the much simpler, cleaner code of the 2nd example.  But if you're not seeing that as a benefit, well, then it's not.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the docs also state: "The purpose of async/await functions is to simplify the behavior of using promises synchronously and to perform some behavior on a group of Promises. Just like Promises are similar to structured callbacks, async/await is similar to combining generators and promises." - There is nothing in that statement about "simpler, cleaner code". It talks about simplifying behavior. I fail to see that in the example they've provided.

Comment: `async` code is much clearer once you do more complex things. Promise chaining is OK, but `async` has a more natural representation of loops and other logic (e.g., `try`/`catch`).

Comment: @Mjh Those are not callbacks. They're promises.

Comment: @AndroidDev - sigh.. i really have no idea why i tried. Have fun and have a nice day. Maybe async await isn't for you, I bet you can do it properly without it.

Comment: Await/Async are functions that return promises, you could think of them as promises with steroids, have a look at this [article](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9) it might help you to have a better understanding

Comment: @FabioAntunes Would it be true to state that you could dispense with using the then()..catch() syntax of Promises and use strictly async functions where they are not required? Or can you foresee having to using both within code?

Comment: If you use external npm packages, you probably will end up using await, promises, callbacks and even observables. It seems you are thinking of this as a right and wrong way of doing async code. There's no need to be strict about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best answer just contains some cool *await* examples.

1) Async looping, e.g. download 10 files in sequence:

```
async function download10(){
  var result=[];
  for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    result.push(await downloadFile(i));
 }
return result;
}
download10().then(console.log);
```

2) chaining async results:

```
try{
  sendFile( await getFile( await checkandReturn(Filepath)));
}catch(e){
  console.error("sending file failed");
}
```

---

Just doing it with Promises looks a bit more ugly:

1)

```
function download10(i=0,result=[]){
 return new Promise(function(res){
   downloadFile().then(function(file){
     result.push(file);
     if(i<10){
       res(download10(i+1,result));
     }else{
       res(result);
     }
   });
 });
}
```

2)

```
checkandReturn(Filepath).then(function(filepath){
  return getFile(filepath);
}).then(function(file){
 return sendFile(file);
}).catch(console.log);
```

Comment: This looks good but if I had to rewrite your example with then(), the code might look slightly uglier and hardly much larger in size. I suspect that in an application, there is probably a need to use both formats depending on the situation. If the slightly simpler async format can be used, then it would make sense to use it.

Comment: @AndroidDev exactly. thats the *benefit of async function*